# Magento 2 : Overriding model gives gateway error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override a core model on magento 2 the path of the file is this

```
/vendor/magento/module-company/Model/Role/Validator.php
```

I added this override to my module's di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Company\Model\Role\Validator" type="OSE\Company\Rewrite\Magento\Company\Model\Validator" />
```

AM i doing this correctly?

Comment: Check magento log first. your code in di.xml is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have override the Model Please check this type.

And i am try the model for invoice pdf. Please check May be help you.

first you create the **di.xml**

Magentoinvoice\Custompdf\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/*
 * Copyright © 2016 Rocket Bazaar. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Magentoinvoice\Custompdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Magentoinvoice\Custompdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" />
</config>
```

And in model folder add the you want to override file.

This is my file example please add the your code but add this type

Answer (score 0):

Your di.xml should edit like this

```
<preference for="Magento\Company\Model\Role\Validator" type="OSE\Company\Model\Role\Validator" />
```

and create Validator.php in directory `app\code\OSE\Company\Model\Role`.
this file have content like

```
<?php
namespace OSE\Company\Model\Role;
class Validator extends \Magento\Company\Model\Role\Validator
{
}
```